# Does Chrome handle match correctly?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

My understanding is that one can use either of the two methods for case-insensitive regex based matches in JavaScript: `match(/pattern/i)` or `match("pattern","i")`. I'm not getting the second variation to work in Chrome though. (I'm using Chromium 14.0.835.202). Is this a bug in Chrome? (or a user error?)

In Firefox when I run this code I get: Hello World and then Hello World. In Chrome I get Hello World, undefined.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click me!" onclick="buttonClick()" />

</body>

<script language="javascript">
function buttonClick()
{
  str="Hello World"
  alert(str.match(/hello world/i))
  alert(str.match("hello world","i"))
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. Firefox allows the use of the `flags` parameter in `String.match`, but as noted on the Mozilla Documentation (or rather, as it *used* to be noted - [this functionality is no longer even mentioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)) it's nonstandard and should be avoided. Also, it's usually less efficient.

If you need this functionality, use `new RegExp` instead.

Comment: And, page 145 of the [ECMAscript v5.1 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) does not mention a second parameter for `.match()`